# How to make use of something like Factory in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use some good coding standards for the current project. The overall outcome is achievable now (in my project), but i want help regarding following a better approach.

I'll try my best to explain what I am doing.

I have a xml Response for `System` and `Product` information (The xml is too big to accomodate here 1MB approx)

I have two panes **left Pane** (an accordion listing what is to be clicked) **right Pane** (JQUERY UI TABS inside which is JPANEL accomodating JQGRID inside it)

1. When the **left Pane** any item is clicked 3 params are sent, **id** of the anchor tag, **Service Name** & an **alias** (which decides what tab content should be) to `function infa9Services(id,sname,alias){...}`

   `<a id="infa9Services"\>DataIntegrationService</a>` //this is the Service Name

   alias is coming from a map, which maps service Name to a alias **DIS** (in one case)
2. The **Right Pane** contains a `<div id="detailTable"></div>` which gets populated from `infa9Services` function.

Content of `infa9Services` function

```
var tabs = [ "Service", "Property", "Additional Info" ];    
//Above array creates the Jquery Tab  heading

var lis="";
var divs="";
var panels=[];
var tpanels="";
var adtrs="";

var service=[];
var property=[];
var aDoctor=[];
var homeFileList=[];
var ssaprlist=[];
var refData=[];
```

fetching data from xml response `xml`

```
$(xml).find('product').each(function(){ 
    $(this).children('DomainMeta').each(function(){ 
        $(this).children('Service').each(function(){ 
            if(sname==$(this).attr('name')) //There are more than one service in the xml, so checking which Service name was clicked, in this case DataIntegrationService
            {
                $(this).children('OptionGroup').each(function(){ 

                    if($(this).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf("service") >= 0)
                    {
                        $(this).children('Option').each(function(){ 
                            var srow={};
                            srow.name=$(this).attr('name');
                            srow.value=$(this).attr('value');
                            service.push(srow);
                        });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).children('Option').each(function(){ 
                            var prow={};
                            prow.name=$(this).attr('name');
                            prow.value=$(this).attr('value');
                            property.push(prow);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Now here I am checking using `if else` what alias is it, based on which i'll fetch data

```
    if(alias==="PCIS")  
    {
        $(this).children('addressDoctor').each(function(){ 
            $(this).children('addressDoctor_info').each(function(){ 

                //adding xml values to aDoctor array
            });
        });

        $(this).children('homefilelist').each(function(){ 
            $(this).children('homefilelist_info').each(function(){ 

                //adding xml values to homeFileList array
            });
        });
    }
    else if(alias==="PCRS")
    {
        $(this).children('homefilelist').each(function(){ 
            $(this).children('homefilelist_info').each(function(){ 

                //adding xml values to homeFileList array
            });
        });
    }
    else if(alias==="DIS")
    {
        $(this).children('addressDoctorEngVerDIS').each(function(){ 
            adtrs='<tr width="100%">'+
                '<th class="thPanel" align="left" valign="top" width="40%">'+$(this).children('addressDoctorEngVer_info').attr('name')+'</th>'+
                '<td align="left" width="60%">'+$(this).children('addressDoctorEngVer_info').attr('value')+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';
        });
    }
    else if(alias==="CMS")
    {
        $(this).children('referenceDataLocation').each(function(){ 
            $(this).children('referenceDataLocation_info').each(function(){
                //adding xml values to refData array

            });
        });

        $(this).children('ssaprDirList').each(function(){ 
            $(this).children('ssaprDirList_info').each(function(){
                //adding xml values to  ssaprlist array
            });
        });
    }

});
```

dynamically adding li 's (for UI tabs)

```
$.each(tabs, function(i, item) {
    lis+='<li><a href="#tabs-'+i+'">'+item+'</a></li>';
});
```

dynamically adding div's with class="class" (for JPanel) is there a better way here?

```
panels[0]='<div title="General Information" class="class">'+
            '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
                '<table id="tblService" width="100%"></table>'+
                '<div id="ServiceGridpager"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';

panels[1]='<div title="General Information" class="class">'+
            '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
                '<table id="tblProperty" width="100%"></table>'+
                '<div id="PropertyGridpager"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';
```

Here again I am making use of `if else` what alias is it, based on which i'll populate data from the vars which were fetched before

```
if(alias==="PCIS")
{
    panels[2]='<div title="Address Doctor" class="class" >'+
                    '<table class="jpanelTable">'+
                        '<tbody>'+adtrs+'</tbody>'+
                    '</table>'+
                '</div>';

    panels[2]+='<div title="Address Doctor Configuration" class="class">'+
                    '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
                        '<table id="tblAdditional" width="100%"></table>'+
                        '<div id="AdditionalGridpager"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';

    panels[2]+='<div title="Home File List" class="class">'+
                '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
                    '<table id="tblHomeFileList" width="100%"></table>'+
                    '<div id="HomeFileListGridpager"></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';
}
else if(alias==="PCRS")
{
    panels[2]='<div title="Home File List" class="class">'+
                    '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
                        '<table id="tblHomeFileList" width="100%"></table>'+
                        '<div id="HomeFileListGridpager"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
}
else if(alias==="DIS")
{
    panels[2]='<div title="Address Doctor" class="class" >'+
                '<table class="jpanelTable">'+
                    '<tbody>'+adtrs+'</tbody>'+
                '</table>'+
            '</div>';
}
else if(alias==="CMS")
{
    panels[2]='<div title="Reference Data Location" class="class">'+
                    '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
                        '<table id="tblRefData" width="100%"></table>'+
                        '<div id="RefDataGridpager"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';

    panels[2]+='<div title="SSAPR" class="class">'+
                '<div class="jqUIDiv">'+
                    '<table id="tblSSAPR" width="100%"></table>'+
                    '<div id="SSAPRGridpager"></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';
}
else
{   
    panels[2]='<div title="Additional Information" class="class" >'+
                '<table class="jpanelTable">'+
                    '<tbody>'+
                        '<tr width="100%">'+
                            '<td align="left" style="word-break:break-all;">'+NA+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</tbody>'+
                '</table>'+
            '</div>';
}
```

Note: panel[0],panel[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8ct3.png),panel[2] are contents of the 3 tabs

dynamically adding div 's (content for Jquery UI Tab)

```
$.each(panels, function(i, item) {
    divs+='<div id="tabs-'+i+'">'+item+'</div>';
});
```

adding the whole thing to `detailTable` (**Right Pane**)

```
$('#detailTable').empty();
$('#detailTable').html('<div class="titleBlue"><a href="#" class="navA">Configuration</a>&gt;<a href="#" class="navA">'+productname+'</a>&gt;'+sname+' ('+alias+')</div>');

$("<div id='loadingDiv'><table id='detailTable' width='100%'><tbody><tr><td align='center'>Please wait</td></tr><tr><td align='center'><img src='/csm/view/include/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading'/></td></tr></tbody></table></div>").appendTo('#detailTable');
$('<div id="tabs">'+'<ul>'+lis+'</ul>'+divs+'</div>').appendTo('#detailTable').delay(10).queue(function(){
    $('.class').jPanel({
        'effect'    : 'fade',
        'speed'     : 'medium',
        'easing'    : 'swing'
    });

});
```

More.. JQGrids to populate `tblService`, `tblSSAPR`, `tblRefData` etc tables (not included here)

How can I make use of something like **Factory** or something more **Generic** in such a case? If suppose there are a lot of **alias** to be checked it will be very cumbersome to do it the way I am doing it currently. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Screen shot
[image]

**Update**

My XML content

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="csmclientinfa9.xsl"?>
<csmclient product="infa9" date="12/16/11 12:10 PM" version="1.0">
    <system>
    </system>
    <product>
        <DomainMeta>

            <Service type="PCIntegrationService" name="TestPCInteg" version="" licenseName="lic_PCIS">    //THIS IS PCIS SERVICE
                <ServiceProcess>
                    <Node name="N_1a63931"></Node>
                    <PreStartCommand> null</PreStartCommand>
                    <PostStartCommand> null</PostStartCommand>
                    <JvmOptions> </JvmOptions> 
                    <OptionGroup name="IntegrationServiceProcessOptions">
                        <Option  name="Codepage_Id" value="4" ></Option>
                        <Option  name="$PMSourceFileDir" value="$PMRootDir/SrcFiles" ></Option>
                    </OptionGroup>
                </ServiceProcess>
                <OptionGroup name="IntegrationServiceOptions">
                    <Option  name="ServiceResilienceTimeout" value="180" ></Option>
                </OptionGroup>
            </Service>

            <Service type="DataIntegrationService" name="TestDIS" version="" licenseName="lic_DIS">    //THIS IS DIS SERVICE
                <ServiceProcess>
                    <Node name="N_1163931"></Node>
                    <PreStartCommand> null</PreStartCommand>
                    <PostStartCommand> null</PostStartCommand>
                    <JvmOptions> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms256M -Xmx512M -XX:GCTimeRatio=19 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:NewRatio=2</JvmOptions> 
                    <OptionGroup name="SQLServiceOptions">
                        <Option  name="MaxConcurrentConnections" value="100" ></Option>
                        <Option  name="MaxPlanCacheSize" value="100" ></Option>
                    </OptionGroup>
                    <OptionGroup name="WebServiceOptions">
                        <Option  name="MaxPlanCacheSize" value="100" ></Option>
                    </OptionGroup>
                </ServiceProcess>
                <OptionGroup name="SQLServiceOptions">
                    <Option  name="ConnectionCleanupPeriod" value="30000" ></Option>
                    <Option  name="DTMKeepAliveTime" value="0" ></Option>
                </OptionGroup>
                <OptionGroup name="CoreServiceOptions">
                    <Option  name="SafeModeLevel" value="0" ></Option>
                </OptionGroup>
            </Service>

        </DomainMeta>

        <homefilelist>
            <homefilelist_info permission='-rwxr-xr-x' hardlink='1' owner='idp' group='support' fsize='61597' date='22 Mar 2011' filename='libpmwspsvrcmn.so' />
            <homefilelist_info permission='-rwxr-xr-x' hardlink='1' owner='idp' group='support' fsize='21778' date='22 Mar 2011' filename='libpmorablk.so' />
        </homefilelist>

        <addressDoctor filename='AD100.cfg'>
            <addressDoctor_info name='MemoryUsage' value='1048' />
            <addressDoctor_info name='PreloadingMethod' value='MAP' />
        </addressDoctor>

        <addressDoctorEngVerPCIS>
            <addressDoctorEngVer_info name='EngineVersion' value='5.2.5' />
        </addressDoctorEngVerPCIS>

        <addressDoctorEngVerDIS>
            <addressDoctorEngVer_info name='EngineVersion' value='5.2.6' />
        </addressDoctorEngVerDIS>

        <referenceDataLocation location='/home/idp/av/default'>
            <referenceDataLocation_info permission='-rw-r--r--' hardlink='1' owner='idp' group='support' fsize='196' month='Aug' date='2' time='11:06' filename='copyright.txt'/>    
        </referenceDataLocation>

        <ssaprDirList>
            <ssaprDirList_info permission='-rw-r--r--' hardlink='1' owner='idp' group='support' fsize='2737558' month='Oct' date='14' time='2010' filename='turkey.ysp' />
        </ssaprDirList>
    </product>
</csmclient>
```

**More Updates**

```
        var aDoctor=[];
    var adtrs="";
    var homeFileList=[];

    if(alias==="PCIS")
    {
        $(this).children('addressDoctorEngVerPCIS').each(function(){ 
            adtrs='<tr width="100%">'+
                '<th class="thPanel" align="left" valign="top" width="40%">'+$(this).children('addressDoctorEngVer_info').attr('name')+'</th>'+
                '<td align="left" width="60%">'+$(this).children('addressDoctorEngVer_info').attr('value')+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';
        });

        $(this).children('addressDoctor').each(function(){ 
            $(this).children('addressDoctor_info').each(function(){ 
                var adevrow={};
                adevrow.name=$(this).attr('name');
                adevrow.value=$(this).attr('value');
                aDoctor.push(adevrow);
            });
        });

        $(this).children('homefilelist').each(function(){ 
            $(this).children('homefilelist_info').each(function(){ 
                var row={};
                isPresent=true;
                row.permission=$(this).attr('permission');
                row.hardlink=$(this).attr('hardlink');
                row.owner=$(this).attr('owner');
                row.group=$(this).attr('group');
                row.fsize=$(this).attr('fsize');
                row.date=$(this).attr('date');

                row.filename=$(this).attr('filename');
                homeFileList.push(row);
            });
        });
    }

    /*moving on for HTML construction, panels[..]
    panels[0] is for 1st jquery ui tab
    panels[1] is for 2nd jquery ui  tab
    panels[2] is for 3rd jquery ui  tab*/

    /*I am also using jqGrid, so I am giving one example for PCIS, how I am using aDoctor array */

    if(alias==="PCIS")
    {
        //Additional Information
        if(aDoctor.length>0)
        {
            jQuery("#tblAdditional").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",    
                data: aDoctor,
                colNames:['Name','Value'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'name',index:'name', align:"left"},   
                    {name:'value',index:'value', align:"left"}
                ],

                pager : '#AdditionalGridpager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,50,100],
                scrollOffset:0,
                height: 'auto',
                autowidth:true,
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true
            });

            jQuery("#tblAdditional").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
            jQuery("#tblAdditional").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
        }
        else //i am displaying none in the table
    }

    //So now my panel is complete for PCIS, if you refer my question, all code is available :) I know it's really big, but this is my 1st project and I want it to be better than this :) Thanks
```

Comment: This question has too much code. I'm having a hard time understanding what is the real problem.

Comment: @missingno: Hi, i know.. but if you read the text's (apart from the code) and then refer the code, you'll understand it. I tried my best to describe my problem

Comment: You want somebody to write your code for you...

Comment: @landons it looks like the code is already written but he wants it to be refactored.

Comment: @Jostster & landons: My code is already written, I just want a better approach (more Generic)

Comment: Are you looking for a way to implement the Factory pattern or something to a similar effect in javascript & jquery? Where you'll be able to wrap the code for each "alias" into an object described by an interface and use the interface in your code?

Comment: @Mehdi Maujood: Exactly what i want. :)

Comment: You've already got a bounty out on this question, but I think "how do I refactor my code" type questions are generally a better fit on the [codereview.SE] site.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Thanks i did not knew about Code Review :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Factory** design pattern must have a switch (`if/else` block or associative array) under the hood anyhow.  You won't ever shorten code by using it.  The only benefit you'll get here is that you might hide away or separate some of that long code.  Returning a function from another function, or returning an array where one of the properties is a function (set in the factory) is about as close as you can get to this pattern in JavaScript.  The code sample below show something very much like a factory that is just as good in the JavaScript case, and might be slightly less confusing.

I'm not sure what you mean by **Generic**.  If you're referring to "generics", ala Java or C#, then it won't help you in this scenario.  Generics in those languages help you get around static typing and avoid duplicating *classes*.  You're not using classes at all here.

If you're simply trying to [avoid repeating yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you should look for a functional refactor here.  See what repeats, and what doesn't.  Figure out how you can loop or map to the stuff that doesn't repeat, and write the code that does repeat only once.

For example, I'd use an associative array to map strings to functions for your big `if/else` block, and I'd extract that child-looping code into a more generialized function:

```
function forAll(parentName, childName, action) {
    $(this).children(parentName).each(function(){ 
        $(this).children(childName).each(function(){ 
            action();
        });
    });
}

var aliasToHandlerMap =
{
    "PCIS": function() {
        forAll('addressDoctor', 'addressDoctor_info', function() {
            //adding xml values to aDoctor array
        });
        forAll('homefilelist', 'homefilelist_info', function() {
            //adding xml values to homeFileList array
        });
    },
    "PCRS": function() {
        forAll('homefilelist', 'homefilelist_info', function() {
            //adding xml values to homeFileList array
        });
    },
    "DIS": function() {
        $(this).children('addressDoctorEngVerDIS').each(function(){ 
            adtrs=
            '<tr width="100%">'+
                '<th class="thPanel" align="left" valign="top" width="40%">'+
                    $(this).children('addressDoctorEngVer_info').attr('name')+'</th>'+
                '<td align="left" width="60%">'+
                    $(this).children('addressDoctorEngVer_info').attr('value')+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';
        });
    },
    "CMS": function() {
        forAll('referenceDataLocation', 'referenceDataLocation_info', function() {
            //adding xml values to refData array
        });

        forAll('ssaprDirList', 'ssaprDirList_info', function() {
            //adding xml values to  ssaprlist array
        });
    }
};

// Execute the appropriate handler for the particular alias
var handler = aliasToHandlerMap[alias];
handler();
```

In this case I'd also recommend you name each of those handlers, and build the map using named functions.  I just wanted to show you *visually* how much code compression you get from this.

You should be able to do similar things for your long strings of HTML that you're building.  If they follow a general pattern, make a function for them, and extract the parts that change into parameters that you pass in.

And you generally shouldn't be building styles into your elements (e.g. `align="left" valign="top" width="40%"`).  You should use style sheets that apply to those specific items, applying only CSS classes when necessary, so that you to specify that in only one place.  That should shorten a lot of the element creation code, and might let you use jQuery DOM creation to avoid messy string concatenation code.

All refactoring of long code boils down to an application of the same principle - find out what repeats, and what doesn't repeat.  Extract the part that repeat, and build an iterable or indexable structure out of the part that doesn't repeat.

To start learning how to do generalized refactoring in languages using a Functional Programming style, I suggest you watch [the SICP lecture videos](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/).  They use LISP, but teach you it while you're watching the videos, and the principles apply to every language out there.  That language lends itself extremely well to this type of refactoring, which is why he uses it.

You could also look into [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/), which allows you to take java code and shrink it into a more compact syntax :)  It compiles back into pretty-printed JavaScript, so you don't have to worry about server impact, installing code on client boxes, etc.

Also, check out a few of these links for more reading on general code refactoring:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring
- http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/ (he wrote a book)

Comment: Looks good :) thanks. My db server is currently on maintenance i'll work on re factoring my code from your sources. Very nice explanation

Comment: I am not able to understand `forAll function`. In `aliasToHandlerMap` `>PCIS` forAll is getting called with some parameters, which is a function itself. And the actual called function `forAll` iterates over `parentName` & `childName` which again calls action.. So I am unable to understand what is the relation here in the actual forAll function calling `action()` and the function which calls `forAll()` with params, which again has a function block having `//adding xml values to aDoctor array`

Comment: @AbhishekSimon:  Look at the original code and compare it side by side with both the reduction, and the contents of the `forAll` function.  No less code gets executed, but you don't have to repeatedly write `$(this).children('homefilelist').each(function(){ $(this).children('homefilelist_info').each(function(){` - you instead just write `forAll('addressDoctor', 'addressDoctor_info', function() {`.  It is a minor reduction of duplication, but it is a simple example of the sort of pattern you should be looking for in all code duplication.

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: See this fiddle for a contrast between something that works like the original code, and something that works like the updated code - http://jsfiddle.net/r744j/ - You can see the exact same work is done, but the pattern is abstracted so you can focus on the implementation and differences between each code block a bit, since the plumbing isn't getting in the way.  If you provide some sample XML building code I could also show you how to eliminate some of the duplication *inside* those blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link.. i am looking at it right now, also I put a small (relevant) portions of my xml content, which contains 2 services `PCIS` & `DIS` along with it, it also contains `homefilelist`, `addressDoctor`, `referenceDataLocation`, `addressDoctorEngVerPCIS`, `addressDoctorEngVerDIS` & `ssaprDirList` nodes to give you a picture of what information gets generated under which service.

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: Ooops, I meant HTML building code, not the source XML :)  The XML I can guess from the structure of the code that builds the HTML.  The code is what we're trying to refactor.

Comment: I don't understand, the HTML building code is already present in my question, what else do you mean by `HTML building code`? adding tables to `panels[..]` and then adding panels[..] to `divs` (jquery UI tabs) and in turn adding it to `detailTable` div

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: I guess there's a lot of code in that question so I'm getting lost :)  I meant the part in the comments that you didn't include, e.g. `//adding xml values to homeFileList array`.  I can take a look at the code you have further down, e.g. `panels[2]= ...` too.  It's gonna take me a while tho, I'll probably have to look at that tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for sticking around & helping me :) I have included one example for `PCIS` service, how i use the array in jqGrid. It's ok help me out in your free time tomorrow, till then i'll try myself. Also if you read about `panels[..]` in my question now, you'll be able to understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, if you get some time, can you help me out with a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I took a look at that code.  There's so much unique data and logic throughout it that I'm not recognizing many patterns.  The best idea is to generate the content correctly to begin with so you don't have to do such drastic transforms on it.  You can couple that with returning JSON from an API rather than trying to parse the HTML content of the page and stuffing it into arrays.  Here's what I got out of that last code update - not a lot of changes - http://jsfiddle.net/bD2vd/

Comment: You also might be able to push the logic into functions that search for items with specific `alias` values so you don't have to stuff them all into a big set of `if`/`else` statements.  Use a traversal function that accepts an `index` so that you can keep the order (if it is important to keep them all in the same array).  You can also use [the `.map` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to build arrays off DOM queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a better way to make your code without having to hard code the html? If that is the case you could use `jQuery.template()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/. It's in beta but it should help you by not having to hardcode your html into the javascript.

For my projects we do our templating in PHP and just have jquery do ajax calls if the data or templates need to change.

If this is not what you are looking for can you be more descriptive with your question?

Comment: Thanks for the information, it might be helpful when it gets released, right now i don't want any such `if` conditions clubing up my space eg: `if(alias==="PCIS")` I want a more uniform way where depending upon the alias it should decide what content should it have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at refactoring further you can use the same jPanel to buld tabs using just a simple div markup like you did for accordion just replace your jPanel js file with the latest 1.4 version that will save some markup junk for you and also you have too much of html as strings try using a javascript template engine here